# convert any base to base 10 in C++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int validnumber(int b, char* p);
unsigned long base2dec(int b,char *p);
void dec2base (int b,unsigned long x);

char *number;


main() {
    int base,temp=0,count;
    unsigned long Decimal_number;

    do {
        printf ("Give the base of the number you want to tranform:");
        scanf ("%d", &base);
        if (base<2 || base>16)
            printf("Not acceptable base number, numbers should be in range from 2 to 16\n\n");
    } while (base<2 || base>16);


    printf ("Give the number you want to tranform:");
    scanf("%s", number);

    for (count=0;count<32;count++) {
        number [count]= toupper(number[count]);
    }

    temp=validnumber(base, number);

    if (temp==0)
        printf ("O arithmpos pou eisagatai periexei MH egkira symbola\n");
    else 
        if (temp==1)
            printf ("O arithmpos pou eisagatai periexei egkira symbola\n");

    if (temp==1) {
        Decimal_number =  base2dec( base , number);     
    }

int validnumber(int b, char *p){

    int  count, a[32];

    for (count=0;count<32;count++)
            a[count]=p[count];

    if (b>=2 && b<=10) {
        for (count=0;count<32;count++) {
            if (a[count]<48 || a[count]>48+b)
                return 0;

            break;
        }
    }

    if (b>=11 && b<=16) {
        for (count=0;count<32;count++) {
            if ((a[count]>=48 && a[count]<=57) || (a[count]>=65 && a[count]<=70)) {
                return 1;
            }

        }
    }   

}
```

From this point the main program must call the function:

```
unsigned long base2dec (int b, char * p)
```

which accepts as arguments the base b and a pointer p in character table that
corresponds to the imported string s and returns the number representing the s expressed in the decimal system. 
Also, it should call the function:

```
void dec2base (int b, unsigned long x)
```

which accepts as arguments the base b and the value of the number x in the decimal system and displays the base value and the representation of the number x in this base. The main program calls this function for all of the base values from 2 to 16.

Are there any ideas on how to begin? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you write that code? Your use of blocked (`{ // blocked }`) and unblocked `if` and `for` loops actively harm reading and seem to promote negative results.

Comment: Also, can you give more explanation on your base2dec? Are you just converting a string to it's decimal representation?

Comment: Yur print statements can be worded better. It can be "Give the base to which you want to convert to" instead of what you have.

Comment: Part of the code is mine yes and also I am converting  an unsigned number saved as a string that must belong from base 2 to 16 to the one with base 10

Answer (score 1):

In your base2dec, you will simply call this method and pass in 'b' as it is and x which should be the converted string.

Here is an implementation of dec2base. It is implemented recursively.

```
void dec2base(int b, unsigned long x){
  if (x == 0)
     return;
  int y = x % b;
  x /= b;
  if (y < 0)
     x += 1; 
  dec2base(b, x);
  //converted digits to hex after realizing this solution doesn't work 
  //for bases greater than 10. Credits to Trevor pointing this out.
  cout<< hex << y < 0 ? y + (b * -1) : y;
  return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please have a look at your formatting because the way your code is written makes it harder than it needs to be to follow.

Here is what I would do:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

void dec2base(int b, long x)
{
    // Quick check for zero
    if (x == 0)
    {
        std::cout << '0';
        return;
    }

    // Print the negative sign if present, also negate
    if (x < 0)
    {
        std::cout << '-';
        x = -x;
    }

    char buf[12];
    int i = 0;

    // Convert to a backwards BCD
    do {
        buf[i++] = static_cast<char>(x % b);
    } while (x /= b);

    // Print it starting from the last digit (really the first)
    do {
        if (buf[--i] <= 9) std::cout << static_cast<char>(buf[i] + '0');
        else std::cout << static_cast<char>(buf[i] + ('a' - 10));
    } while (i);
}

long base2dec(int b, char * p)
{
    long digit;           // Current digit
    long mul = 1;         // Current multiplier
    char *pos = p;        // Current position
    bool neg = false;     // Sign
    long ret = 0;         // The return value

    // Find the last digit
    while (*pos) pos++;

    // Continue until the start of the string is reached
    while (pos-- != p)
    {
        if (*pos < '0')
        {
            if (*pos == '-')
            {
                // Sign reached, save it an break out
                neg = true;
                break;
            }
            else  // Shouldn't happen
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Not a number");
            }
        }
        if (*pos > 'f')
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not a number");

        // Get a digit
        if (*pos <= '9') digit = *pos - '0';
        else if (*pos >= 'a') digit = *pos - ('a' - 10);
        else if (*pos >= 'A' && *pos <= 'F')
            digit = *pos - ('A' - 10);
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not a number");

        // Make sure it is not larger than or equal to the base
        if (digit >= b)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not a number");

        // Add the digit
        ret += digit * mul;

        // Increase the multiplier
        mul *= b;
    }
    return neg ? -ret : ret;
}

int main()
{
    long val = base2dec(16, "123f");
    dec2base(16, val);
    return 0;
}
```

I realize you didn't ask for a signed version but as it is very easy to implement I have done it. If you really don't need to deal with signed values it is simple to drop the relevant parts from the functions.

This is a very quick and dirty go at this and this could no doubt be improved both for readability and performance but is, I think, a good starting point.

Here is a slightly improved version of base2dec():

```
long base2dec(int b, char * p)
{
    long digit;           // Current digit
    bool neg = false;     // Sign
    long ret = 0;         // The return value

    // Check for negative number
    if (*p == '-')
    {
        neg = true;
        p++;
    }

    // Continue until the end of the string is reached
    for (; *p != 0; p++)
    {
        // Rough range check
        if (*p < '0' || *p > 'f')
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not a number");

        // Get a digit
        if (*p <= '9') digit = *p - '0';
        else if (*p >= 'a') digit = *p - ('a' - 10);
        else if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'F')
            digit = *p - ('A' - 10);
        else
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not a number");

        // Make sure it is not larger than or equal to the base
        if (digit >= b)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Not a number");

        // Add the digit
        ret = ret * b + digit;
    }
    return neg ? -ret : ret;
}
```

Regarding the validnumber() function. This check is best performed during the conversion both to avoid having to read the entire string twice and because base2dec() really ought to check for valid input anyway. If you still need a separate check then you need to fix validnumber(). There is no need to copy the string to an array and it is also better to use the same code for all bases. Here is a suggestion:

```
bool validnumber(int b, char *p)
{
    // Check for valid base
    if (b < 2 || b > 16) return false;

    // Extract numeric and alpha parts of the base
    int b_numeric = b <= 10 ? b : 10;
    int b_alpha = b - 11;

    // Ignore any sign
    if (*p == '-') p++;

    // Continue until the end of the string
    for (; *p != 0; p++)
    {
        // Digits < 0 are always bad
        if (*p < '0') return false;

        // Check for valid numeric digits
        if (*p > ('0' + b_numeric))
        {
            // Check for valid alpha digits
            if (b <= 10) return false;
            if (*p < 'A' || *p > ('a' + b_alpha)) return false;
            if (*p > ('A' + b_alpha) && *p < 'a') return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I duly noted your suggestion. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know that this code is difficult to read but I try to learn how to handle strings though my knowledge stops with numbers. What I try to do in the part I wrote is control the number-string somenone gives so it has the correct characters and even that works not for all the inputs.

Comment: Trevor, I am studying your code now and I like this style. Can you point to a direction of a good book or other media in order to learn to write code close to yours?

Comment: I learned C++ back when the idea of an ISO standard was but the fevered dream of a madman, so most of my old texts are hopelessly out of date.  These days for references I generally go to either www.cplusplus.com or www.cppreference.com - the former is easier to follow but the latter is more detailed.  Both have tutorials but if you are coming from a low level you might be better to look elsewhere.  All of the code I posted is standard C except for std::cout, static_cast and exceptions, .  The style is typical of how you will find C written (excepting for personal taste).

Comment: To follow the code you need to know about C/C++ topics like ASCII, pointers, and normal arithmatic.  Pretty much any elementary C/C++ tutorial or book worth anything will teach you about these topics.  You will also need general maths topics like binary coded decimal (BCD) and base conversion and there are countless tutorials covering these topics out there.

Comment: You have the rep to comment now, so why don't you trim your answer by moving the comment part out? It will make it much clearer.